# Error while adding Hash Key to the facebook application

Tags: android, facebook

I got this error while adding the hash key to the facebook application, for SSO in my android application

error:

```
You have enabled a Mobile Web integration for your app, but have not specified Mobile Web URL.
```

what does this mean ? i never used android-facebook sdk before

while going through link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#register
i saw a box names Mobile Web Url:[?], what is this and what should be in there???

Comment: you want to generate key hash  or you got error on facebook page?

Comment: i generated the key hash....now i want to add it to my facebook web application, during which i faced this error

Comment: You want to integrate Facebook in Android or Web?

Comment: are you  developing facbook mobile app or web app?

Comment: i didnt develop mobile or web app for facebook. but there is a web app available on facebook created by someone else, which i want to use

Comment: @Venky i want to integrate my android app to fb.....i got login with FB  option in my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below image , your Application Settings should be like this :

[image]

Don't check anything other than this.

After doing this , generate **Hash Key** and put in respective field.

Comment: and are you sure this will work is i am using a facebook web application id as my AppID in my android application??

Comment: i mean is the web app can be used for integration of android with facebook??...or should i create a facebook mobile app?

Comment: and 1 more doubt...now that i am using this hashkey on the facebook web app....how does it know that it is going to be integrated with my android application???....is it the AppID of facebook web app which i used in my android application links them??

Comment: You will have only one App ID , use it for both Web and Mobile.. Also there is some ways to generate Hash Key for Mobile Device. Follow that.

Comment: no i want to know what is the link between my android application and my facebook web application??....is it the AppID i use in my android app connects to the facebook web app?...if so what is the use of the hash key...where is the hashkey validated?? there must be something like hash key in my android app is same as hash key in my facebook web app

Comment: I am coming to tell that you Mobile App and Web app is not having relation. You can use same App Id for mobile an web. Also I don't have idea about Web... For Mobile if you create hash Key and save it will enables Single Sign ON... Please ask for Web experts regarding this..

Comment: and the image out posted: is there a need to fill the other 3 boxes below hash key???

Comment: 1 last question....is this hash key used anywhere in my android application code??

Comment: No not at all.. This is Enabled by default , if you need to disable you need to add extra parameter in Authorize method..

Comment: i posted this question because i am getting this error: "Login Failed: invalid_key: Android Key mismatch. Your key "YLYMBqpjl/Oene......" does not match the allowed keys specified in your application settings, check your app settings at www.facebook.com/developers"......to solve this i got a hash key and  added it in my app settings on facebook(just like u said)...but still i get the same error....where did this key in my error message came from??

Comment: Way you create Key may be wrong , there are number of Post in SO please check it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12229/discussion-between-archie-bpgc-and-venky)

Comment: can i disable android native deeply linking??....where does this effect?? the way i created my key is fine i checked it..

Answer (score 1):

By mistakely you have checked website with facebook login checkbox.

uncheck it and it will work.

[image]

Comment: i will try that, but can you please explain me what Mobile Web Url is??....where is it useful and what must be in there??